# Can't find stylesheet to import. @use '@material/rtl/rtl';

Tags: angular, angular-material, sass-loader

When I serve my application, I get this build error:

```
ERROR in ./src/sass/app.scss (./node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js!./node_modules/postcss-loader/dist/cjs.js??ruleSet[1].rules[1].use[2]!./node_modules/sass-loader/dist/cjs.js??ruleSet[1].rules[1].use[3]!./src/sass/app.scss)
Module build failed (from ./node_modules/sass-loader/dist/cjs.js):
Can't find stylesheet to import.
   ╷
27 │ @use '@material/rtl/rtl';
   │ ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
   ╵
  @material/button/_button.scss 27:1                                         @use
  node_modules/@angular/material/button/_button-theme.scss 2:1               @use
  node_modules/@angular/material/core/density/private/_all-density.scss 2:1  @forward
  @angular/_index.scss 19:1                                                  @use
  src/sass/material-theming/custom-theme.scss 1:1                            @import
  src/sass/app.scss 45:9                                                     root stylesheet
 @ ./src/sass/app.scss 8:6-246 22:17-24 26:7-21 52:25-39 53:36-47 53:50-64 57:6-67:7 58:54-65 58:68-82 64:42-53 64:56-70 66:21-28 77:0-216 77:0-216 78:22-29 78:33-47 78:50-64 55:4-68:5
 @ ./src/ts/app.ts 2:0-26
```

This happens when I upgrade from Angular15 to Angular16. I am able to use my Editor to navigate to the @material/rtl/rtl file.

I can confirm that it does exist. Does anyone have any idea why `sass-loader` cannot find the stylesheet?